# Preventing Access graph from auto updating on access form open

Tags: vba, ms-access, graph

I have a few graphs on my form. The problem is the source for these graphs is a query that is only created once user selects a few things on the form. Everything works however when I first open the form I get a few errors for the graphs saying basically the source can't be found(normal since it doesnt exist). The error is " an error occurred while sending data to the ole server"

How do I either prevent the graphs from auto updating or supress those errors.

- I tried the property graph.autoactivate=false but that doesnt work.
- There is an update option in the graph properties however access wont let me set it to manual for some reason.
- DoCmd.SetWarnings also doesnt seem to work.
- also tried blanking row source and setting it once the graph is ready but that too seems to have no effect.

thanks

Comment: no it is a simple bar graph no pivot tables

Comment: To resolve, give graph a default recordsource available when form opens and then have user adjust with form items.